# Redmine paste-image-from-clipboard not working after upgrading

Tags: redmine

I have upgrade redmine to 3.3.0 and now the paste-image-from-clipboard function does not work anymore.

Browser shows error as:

```
jcrop-0.9.10.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

Here is the environment settings after upgrading.

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                3.3.0.stable
  Ruby version                   2.3.1-p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  4.2.6
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.6.11
  Mercurial                      1.4
  Git                            1.7.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  clipboard_image_paste          1.8
  redcase                        1.0 beta 2.0
  redmine_code_review            0.6.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your [clipboard_image_paste](https://github.com/peclik/clipboard_image_paste) plugin to the latest version. Only version 1.10 support Redmine 3.x.

Also, since version came along 1.8, the bundled jcrop library was updated to support newer browser versions which will probably resolve your issue.